# how to rewrite the function from spark to pandas

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a dataset in spark with columns group, used,free
in spark the code looks like this:

```
.groupby('group')
        .agg(
            (F.max('used')/678).alias('used'),
            ((F.max('free')+F.max('used'))/678).alias('total')
        )
```

How can I rewrite the second aggregation to pandas? Pandas in aggregation only takes one colony to aggregate, doesn't it?

I tried to pass the following functions:

```
def used(x):
    return max(x)/678
def total(x,y):
    return (max(x)+max(y))/678
```

the second one didn't work

Comment: You can use `groupby.apply`:  `df.groupby(['group']).apply(lambda g: (g.free.max() + g.used.max())/678)`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
f_agg = lambda x: max(x)/678
df_grouped = (df
              .groupby('group')
              .agg({'used': f_agg, 'free': f_agg})
              .reset_index()
             )
df_grouped['total'] = df_grouped['free'] + df_grouped['used']
df_grouped.drop('free', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Hope it helps